# Hibernate criteria with 2 entities table and 1 association table

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I need to make a query inside a DAO using hibernate criteria, but im not sure how.

I have 2 entities, A and B, and an association table, that contains both A and B ID's.
A doesnt know B, and B doesnt know A.

I want to find all A's that are associated with a certain B, using criteria.

I made a diagram, hope it helps to explain.

[Example image](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/2797/eghr.jpg)
[image]

As you can see, table A have 3 records, table B have 3 records too and table AssocAB 3 records as well. I want to find all A's that are associated in AssocAB with B1. The query should return A1 and A3.

is it possible?

Here's the classes, and the relationship annotated.

Entity A: No annotation

Entity B: Have a Set of Entity A

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Assoc_AB", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_B")},  inverseJoinColumn = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_A")})
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_A_B", inverseName = "FK_B_A")
public set<A> getA(){
    return this.listOfA;
}
```

And no class for association class, the mapping on B creates the assoc table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Witch hibernate relationship did you implement?

Comment: OK you are using annotations... pls update your question with this annotations you are using

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just updated my question, now with the annotation mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write a criteria query with your indications, but it's not easy because you tell that `A` and `B` tables have a `int ID`, but then you put `Strings` in your rows (`"A1"`, `"B1"`...). I supposed that your `id` is a `String` instead of an int. You should have something like this:

```
List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<A>();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class, "b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.id", "B1"));
List<B> listOfBs = criteria.list();
for (B b : listOfBs) {
    listOfA.addAll(b.getA());
}
```

If you have a `name` property in `B` class, you would have to modify the restriction:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.name", "B1"));
```

I hope this code can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi! Sorry bout the string/id, but the id type is int. I put A1 and B1 to make it easier to understand, guess didnt work.
Well, that solved my problem actually, and it was easier than i thought...since i have the collection of A on B, all i had to do is to find B and then get it's list...thanks for your help!